# finding out the probability density of a random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions

I have to find out the probability density function of a random process with the following specifications:z(t)= xcos(wt)-ysin(wt) where x and y are two independent gaussian random variables.
Now what i am doing is expressing the above random process in the following form:
z(t)=rcos(wt+A), where r= (x^2 + y^2)^1/2 and A= tan inverse of y/x.
Now the random variable r has a Rayeligh probability density function and A has uniform density function.Thus i am getting expectation of z as 0.
Am i in the right direction and what next should i do in order to find out the probability density function of z.

Comment: If $X$ or $Y$ have nonzero mean, then your statements about the distributions of $R$ and $A$ are not correct. But, to compute the _expectation_ of $Z = X\cos(\omega t) - Y\sin(\omega t)$ does not require any knowledge of $R$ or $A$, not even independence or Gaussianity; knowing $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yeah x and y have zero mean.Now am i correct?

Comment: You cannot deduce $E[Z] = 0$ just from the knowledge that $R$ and $A$ have Rayleigh and uniform distributions respectively: you also need to be able to say that $E[R\cos(\omega t + A)] = E[R]E[\cos(\omega t + A)]$ and then note that $E[\cos(\omega t + A)]] = 0$.

Comment: i can deduce E[z]=0 if i know the joint probability density of R and A.Anyway this problem is much simpler than i thought it to be.Linear combination of gaussian is gaussian and the p.d.f of z is also a gaussian with zero mean.

Comment: `i can deduce E[z]=0 if i know the joint probability density of R and A.` Please read my previous comments again. You **do not need to know anything about $R$ and $A$** to deduce that $E[Z]=0$. As Byron Schmuland has pointed out to you, linearity of expectation suffices. But if you _do_ want to start from **a** joint distribution of $R$ and $A$, then you cannot get to $E[Z]=0$ _in all cases_. You _can_ get to $E[Z]=0$ for the special case when $R$ and $A$ are **independent** random variables, a property that you resolutely refuse to acknowledge is true in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ and $y$ are independent Gaussian random variables, then the linear combination
$$z(t)= x\cos(wt)-y\sin(wt)$$ is also Gaussian. Can you calculate the mean and variance of $z(t)$?

Comment: ...And if really you are interested in the distribution of the *process*, add to the computations Byron suggested the covariance of $Z(t)$ and $Z(s)$ for every $(s,t)$.